# Get inputs of different types in a class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Say I have a jquery function within JavaScript and I have this code so far, which works great:

`jQuery('div[class="someClass"] input[type="text"]').each( function() { //some code} . . .`

In the above code, how can I target multiple types of inputs such as textArea, drop-down list etc. I am pretty new to jQuery so I am not aware of the format a google search did not bring up anything of much relevance! Please help.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're happy to select all descendent elements that are of these types:

- `input`
- `textarea`
- `select`
- `button`

you can use the [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

```
jQuery('div.someClass :input').each(function() {...
```

Otherwise, you can do this in a big selector using the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) as Niklas suggests. One last option is to shorten this by using two selections.  This *may* be slightly slower, but will be significantly more readable:

```
jQuery('div.someClass').find('input[type="text"], select, textarea').each(function(){...
```

Note that I have used the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to make your selector a bit neater.

Answer (score 3):

Separate them with a comma:

```
jQuery('div[class="someClass"] input[type="text"], div[class="someClass"] textarea, div[class="someClass"] select').each( function() { //some code}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery('div[class="someClass"] :input').each(function(){
  //Do Something..
})
```

to avoid button elements try:

```
jQuery('div[class="someClass"] :input:not(:button)').each(function(){
  //Do Something..
})
```