# get checkboxes with textarea and select in a single jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

From the solutions provided by **lonesomeday** on the following link , now I know how to get different inputs in a single jquery. [Get inputs of different types in a class using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299376/get-inputs-of-different-types-in-a-class-using-jquery)

Now I also want to get the `checkboxes` with `textarea` and `select` in a single jquery.

Comment: Read the whole answer, or [the next one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6299403/7469). This question is totally covered by the one you reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get inputs of different types in a class using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299376/get-inputs-of-different-types-in-a-class-using-jquery)

Comment: Yes, I know. I mentioned that link in my questions. But I didn't find the answer for **checkboxes**.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be add a class to them, for example:

```
<textarea class='foo'></textarea>
<input type='checkbox' class='foo' />
<select class='foo'><option val='1'>1</option></select>
```

Then query them using `$('.foo')`

This way, you won't get/fetch something you don't want..

Alternatively, if you don't want to add a `class`, use comma:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"], select, textarea')
```

Comment: i have tried the "alternative" way but `checkbox` doesn't work for me.